# Why does json_encode of a SplFixedArray dump an object instead of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm using `json_encode` to dump an array and I'm getting different results using `array()` and `SplFixedArray`. It gives me array as it should when I use `array()`, but gives me an object when I use an `SplFixedArray`. Is there a reason for this?

This is what is returned when I use a normal array():

```
[{"firstName":"Bo","middleName":"N","lastName":"Higgs"},
 {"firstName":"Bob","middleName":"D","lastName":"Superstar"}]
```

And when I use a SplFixedArray it gives me:

```
{"0":{"firstName":"Bo","middleName":"N","lastName":"Higgs"},
 "1":{"firstName":"Bob","middleName":"D","lastName":"Superstar"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two string are exactly the same, SplFixedArray only has a little different way of storing it, as it is a FIXED array. [simple demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/da43711f576a687f555fde0b7a6e28d5b7b8c4f6)

Also be sure to read the manual. If you initiate SplFixedArray (it is a class, not a function) you get an object in return. The manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php

Comment: The two strings are entirely different, a JSON array is not a JSON object. Try decoding it in another language than PHP and you'll understand. Only PHP treats all arrays as hashmaps, and it's weird as hell that its only real array type `SplFixedArray` JSONs into an object.